# Reading system_health*.xel files efficiently

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I want to gather granular details of an SQL deadlock. I am trying to use this query for that.
Since I have to run this in a production environment, I am worried if it will cause an overhead. Is there any filters that i can apply such that the dataset be limited to today or yesterday?

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, event_data) DeadLockXMLData
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY Object_name
        ) DeadLockNumber
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'system_health*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'xml_deadlock_report'
```

Comment: The [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) denotes there is a column to do so; why can you not use that one? Are you on SQL Sevrer 2016 or prior?

Comment: if you have performance problems reading deadlock trace files, maybe the performance isn't the biggest issue, but in worst case, you can always offload them into a test server and read them there or bulk insert them into a table

Comment: Yes, @ThomA the documentation has one of the examples that uses `timestamp_utc` column apply a timeframe as filter. thanks!

Comment: @ThomA Oh! yes, I am using version 14.x and I see this `timestamp_utc` is not available in that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i can use this for the need. from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('system_health*.xel', null, null, null)
WHERE timestamp_utc > dateadd(day, -1, GETUTCDATE())
```

PS: this `timestamp_utc` Applies to: SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later and Azure SQL Database.

Comment: The cast is unnecessary

Comment: removed the cast

Comment: Though, for some reason, it's in the documentation, @Charlieface . >_< "Love it" when Microsoft Documentation does silly stuff like `CAST`ing a `datetime2(7)` to a `datetime2(7)`.